# excel hide part of name

Tags: vba, excel

[image: Duplicate dropdown names]

For my vlookup to function properly I added a # at the end of "Truck Stock" but I don't want that number to be visible. Anyway of hiding it with the NumberFormat option?

Comment: can you show an example of your `String` ? and what would you like the result to look like ? Maybe we can offer a better solution

Comment: Use a helper column that you hide, This column that is hidden is the one you use for the lookup and the other has what you want displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clear picture of what exactly your situations is but I would hazard a guess something like this is what you want:

```
=LEFT( TRUCK_STOCK_VLOOKREF, FIND( DELIMITER, TRUCK_STOCK_VLOOKREF ) - 1 )
```

Change `DELIMITER` to some kind of unique separator (I would suggest a pipe `|` character if that's not commonly used for you) and use this delimiter to separate the number from the stock name.